# Python 3.6 Lemmatization Errors (Object of type 'NoneType has no len())

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, lemmatization, object-type

I have two records in a SQL DB:

```
id     text
1      The farmer plants grain
2      The fisher catches fish.
```

I have a function to clean, tokenize, POS tag, and lemmatize the text field. The function continues on to join the tokens back together. Then, the data is loaded and each record in the `text` field is looped through that function:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):

    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return ''

def documentToWords(rawDocument):
    noHTML = BeautifulSoup(rawDocument, 'lxml').get_text()
    lettersOnly = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', noHTML)
    tokens = word_tokenize(lettersOnly.lower())
    stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stops]
    tokensPOS = pos_tag(tokens)
    tokensLemmatized = []
    for w in tokensPOS:
        tokensLemmatized.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w[0], get_wordnet_pos(w[1])))
    tokensLemmatized = str(tokensLemmatized)
    return(" ".join(tokensLemmatized))

engine = sa.create_engine(<driver_info>)
data = pd.read_sql('select id, text from test_table', engine)

numDocuments = data['text'].size
cleanDocuments = []
for i in range(0, numDocuments):
    cleanDocuments.append(documentToWords(data['text'][i]))

print(cleanDocuments)
```

The result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-280f7c5bba43>", line 44, in <module>
    cleanDocuments.append(documentToWords(data['text'][i]))

  File "<ipython-input-27-280f7c5bba43>", line 25, in documentToWords
    noHTML = BeautifulSoup(rawDocument, 'lxml').get_text()

  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Expected Result:

```
['farmer plant grain','fisher catch fish']
```

I have two problems:

1. The current error - I have read numerous other issues related to this error, but cannot figure out how it is affecting my code. When I remove the `noHTML` line, the traceback merely points to the next line in the function
2. The conversion of the lemmatized list back into a string may be contributing to problem one, as I'm not sure if that's the proper way to perform that action.

How should I adjust to remove the error and properly lemmatize the `text` field?